# How to get a second specific word inside a string in PHP

Tags: php

Hey guys so I have a question,

Lets say someone puts `"Hi lets have #fun and than more #fun"` Now lets say I want to grab the second hashtag including the word connected to it and store it into a variable.

How would I go about getting the second part because using `(strpos($a,'#fun')` would only return the first one.

Thank you for your time!

David

Edit:

Here's what I did:

```
$code = "Hi lets have #funfgs and than more #funny";
$pos1 = strpos($code, '#');
$pos2 = strpos($code, '#', $pos1 + strlen('#'));
echo substr($code, $pos2);
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar will this work even if there are other words in between the first and second parameter I want, they will always be different.  The main thing I point out is the #

Comment: @DavidBiga yes, it should still work. It's just using `strpos` on a haystack that has the first occurrence of the needle stripped out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following Regular Expression

```
$code = "Hi lets have #fun and than more #fun";

$pattern = "$#[^\s]*$i";

preg_match_all($pattern, $code, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Its pattern matching using regular expressions. Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: I'm getting `Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string`

Comment: Okay I removed the $'s and its working.....the thing is it gives me every single letter in arrays?

Comment: Check the edit. It might help. You get all the hashtags and you can loop through the array to get what you need.

Comment: Ya that is not working.